# Desktop Entry for JavaFIBS

Tags: gnome, software-installation, openjdk

I'm trying to create a Desktop Entry for a game called Java FIBS. It uses jre as its environment.

This is the file I've created, but can't seem to get it to execute:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Game
Terminal=false
Exec=env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/openjdk-11/ ~/JavaFIBS2001/JavaFIBS-1.0.11_JDK16.jar
Name=JavaFIBS
Icon=~/JavaFIBS2001/JavaFIBS.ico
```

I suspect the problem has to do with the way I've set the environment but can't seem to figure it out.

Any assistance is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done some fiddling and have been able to figure out the solution to this question. I place it here for posterity and just in case it might be useful for someone else.The ensuing answer assumes that java is installed in `/usr/lib64/openjdk-11/bin/java`. To be sure where java is installed, you can run `which java` in the terminal to see its path and substitute that below where you see `/usr/lib64/openjdk-11/bin/java`.

0. Begin by downloading both the java program and installing the jre/jdk from the software center.
1. Having installed jre/jdk, create a symlink from your java installation path to the `/usr/bin/` directory. In my case, I ran the following command in a terminal because I installed openjdk-11:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/openjdk-11/bin/java /usr/bin/java
   ```
2. Create the following Desktop Entry in a text editor of your choice, replacing `USERNAME` with your correct username:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Categories=Application;Game;BoardGame
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=
   Exec=java -jar '/home/USERNAME/JavaFIBS2001/JavaFIBS-1.0.11_JDK16.jar'
   Path=/home/USERNAME/JavaFIBS2001/
   Name=JavaFIBS
   Icon=/home/USERNAME/JavaFIBS2001/JavaFIBS.ico
   Comment=Play backgammon online
   ```

   (Of course, you will point it to the specific java program and its location on your system.)
3. Save the file you created in `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications`. (Do ensure the name of the file ends in `.desktop`).
4. Run the following command in the terminal

   ```
   chmod a+x /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/FILENAME.desktop
   ```

You should now be able to select the program from your applications menu.

In case you are curious, JavaFIBS is client that allows you to play backgammon online against real people and robots at fibs.com and ti-ga.com (the latter site is presently down because of a server failure).